# Docker Website using Node and Yarn wont let we access website

Tags: docker

I just started writing docker files and am trying to start a website using docker but every time I run the file I cant access the website.
[dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Bpr.png)
[dockerlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7BeG.png)

Comment: 1. provide container logs 2. try access from container's localhost

Comment: @LeiYang I add the container log and im not quite sure how to access the containers localhost

Comment: paste log text here. don't use links or images.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a warning that the method is deprecated and does not affect the running of the application, it is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: you can run `docker exec -it $containerId bash`, then `open http://localhost:3000/`

Answer (score -1):

I actually figured it out when running the docker run command adding the
--network="host" flag let me connect to the website

Comment: This generally disables Docker's networking features.  It means you can't choose a different host port or choose to not publish the container port at all, and it means you will have trouble connecting between containers.  I would not generally recommend this as a solution.